# shiny datatables with column filters not showing selections

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I am showing a datatable in a shiny app with column filters at top.

The problem I have is that when I select some values in a column, they don't show up as selected when I click outside the table (although the table gets modified to show only the rows with selected values).

E.g., below is the table shown with `mtcars` dataset. Focus on the `cyl` column, I am selecting `4` and `6`. I converted `cyl` from `numeric` to a 'factor` so that it will appear as a drop-down while filtering.

[image]

The selection works (I don't see any `8` in the `cyl`, but there is no way to tell which values of `cyl` have been selected. I see a similar behavior with the other columns also.

Is there any way to show the selections also in the filter box?

Thanks!
SN248